# Mulesoft Deploy via VPN no Internet

Tags: mulesoft

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W41T2.png)

Just asking if can we deploy using maven command or other tools depends only tunneling without internet. Lets says anypoint.mulesoft.com is block.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a different URL in the `<uri>` element of the `<cloudHubDeployment>` configuration. You will have to test if that works, because it will probably fail the TLS certificate host name validation if you change it.